# Move or copy the results of a find call in mac osx terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command, line

I have a large directory full of various shapefiles. I'd like to move or copy all of the files ending in _31. or _32. to a different directory (mac osx).

```
## Find all shapefiles ending in 31
find ./ -iname '*_31.*' 2>/dev/null

## Find all shapefiles ending in 32
find ./ -iname '*_32.*' 2>/dev/null
```

The above find calls successfully find all of the desired files. Now I'd like to move or copy those results to the new directory. Any ideas?

Comment: I used find ./ -iname '*_32.*' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} ../.. and it worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a job for xargs!

`find ./ -iname '*_32.*' |  xargs  -I _ cp _ destination`

xargs will take the output of find and run a command on each line.

`-I _` sets a place holder for the incoming line that is then used in the cp command.